# Cannot open port 3001 to local IPV4 ubuntu lts 20.04

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm creating a back end app with NodeJs. My app running at port `3001`. It is accessible when i try to access it with `localhost:3001` or `0.0.0.0:3001` or `127.0.0.1:3001`, but when I try to access it with another device, it's mean I try to access with local ip (same network) `192.168.1.8`, it is **not working**.

So, I try to open my port with ufw

```
sudo ufw allow 3001
```

and I check the ufw status with `sudo ufw status verbose`, this is the result is like below:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
2222                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
3001/tcp                   ALLOW IN    192.168.1.8               
53                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
192.168.1.8 3001/tcp       ALLOW IN    127.0.0.1                 
3001                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
2222 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
3001 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

but when I try to `nmap 192.168.1.8`. I saw the port not opened, here is the result from my nmap.

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-18 12:43 WIB
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.8 (192.168.1.8)
Host is up (0.00014s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.1.8 (192.168.1.8) are closed

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

but when I try to `nmap localhost`, the port `3001` has opened.

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-18 12:44 WIB
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00014s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
631/tcp  open  ipp
3001/tcp open  nessus

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

So, how to open my port to my local ip that accessible with another device in the same network?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is nodeJS listening on all interfaces? What is the output of `sudo lsof -i :3001` or `sudo netstat -tunlp | grep ":3001"` ?

Comment: ```
COMMAND   PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    15136 aequaliter   22u  IPv4 173728      0t0  TCP localhost:3001 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: that is the output of sudo lsof -i :3001

Comment: That shows you are only listening on the loopback (localhost) interface. You need to configure nodejs to listen on all interfaces (I think via your nodejs server.listen() call).

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: btw, thank you for your information, i'll try to find it on the framework docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an example, node.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port=3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`));
```

And then:

```
# lsof -i :3000
COMMAND    PID  USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    201089 wayne   21u  IPv6 2249996      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

`*:3000` indicates port 3000 on all interfaces. Note that even though it says IPv6 it is actually listening IPv4 as well since we did not specify ipv6Only ([nodejs server.listen doc](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_options_callback)).

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm using fastify. I'll try to find something on fastify docs that make it listen on all interfaces.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Wayne. It solved.

Comment: maybe for anyone using fastify that have the same problem with me. can open this link to solve it....
https://www.fastify.io/docs/v1.13.x/Server/